# React.js web app not opening in Brave or Safari - globalThis

Tags: node.js, reactjs, brave

I got a React environment and the app works when in Chrome but not in Safari or Brave.

The console error Brave gives is this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (byte-utils.js:5)
```

And the line 5 in reference is this:

```
const useBuffer = globalThis.process && !globalThis.process.browser && globalThis.Buffer && typeof globalThis.Buffer.isBuffer === 'function';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Brave and older versions of Safari [don't support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) - it's a somewhat new object, after all.

You can either [include a polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/globalthis) or simply reference `window` instead of `globalThis` - the global object in a browser is the window (except in workers, where you need to use `self` instead of `window`).

Comment: How to actually use npm `globalthis` package in a React app though?